# Do changes need to be made to the Moto Sagepay backoffice integration to support 3D Secure V2?

Tags: opayo

We currently utilise MOTO and Sagepay within our ERP software to process credit/debit card payments in the back office. Looking on the sagepay system, these come through as using the 'Direct' system, which the [3D Secure V2 details page](https://www.sagepay.co.uk/support/16/3d-secure-v2-what-do-customers-need-to-do) suggests will have to change to support 3DSV2. However, 3DS isn't currently used at all in the back office. Will this change, i.e. will 3DSV2 be mandated for transactions for this, or can we continue as is and not worry?

Answer (score 0):

Strong Customer Authentication is a requirement for all ecommerce transactions. It is AccountType=E in Sage Pay Direct. All MOTO transactions are AccountType=M and don't have 3DS by default. Make sure that your customer is off-session and payment is made by your employee in the back office system, not by the customer.

Check also https://www.sagepay.co.uk/support/12/36/3d-secure-explained